# MySQL search with typo

Tags: mysql, search, elasticsearch, instant

In my MySQL database I have a user table. I need to perform search as you type with typo over the user name field. There are few very old question on this topic. I tested the builtin full text search of mysql but it didn't work as expected (it does not handle typo) [I knew but I tried anyway].
What's my best option? I thought there should be an easy solution nowadays. I'm thinking about replicating the user table on elasticsearch and do the instant search from there, but I'd really like to avoid the syncronization nightmare that this will cause.

Thanks!!

Comment: If the user name is a single word you can try [SOUNDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex). We had the same issue and moved to elastic search, It is totally worth the effort of synchronisation as it took a huge load from the DB (30% in my case)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think soundex is good enough. Can you give me a brief description of how you approached the synchronisation? How can you be sure that the two DB are aligned after a long period of time?

Comment: It is a bit tedious. On the DB we created a trigger on the table that is present in the ES index. This trigger would add all the id's of the rows that change and store the ids in a table. We created a cron job that would read from that table and send the ids to a queue on rabbitmq. We used a queue so that it becomes resistant to failures. and wrote a consumer that would update the index in ES. our table usually has a very low update rate (5 updates a sec). If the updates/inserts are large then this will be difficult

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to use the same approach. I also have a similar update/insert rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SOUNDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) for mysql. We have tried that but I can say that it does not work that well and it also makes the search a bit slow.

We Had a similar issue and switched to ES.

What we did is as follows:

- Created a trigger for the table that will be synced to ES. The
  trigger will write to a new table. The columns of such a table would
  be:

  > IdToUpdate Operation DateTime IsSynced

  The Operation would be create, update, delete. IsSynced will tell
  whether the update is pushed to ES.
- Then add a corn job that would query this table for all rows that will have issynced set to say '0', Add those ID's and operation to a Queue like RabbitMQ. And set the ISSynced to 1 for those ID's

  The reason to use RabbitMQ is that it will make sure that the update is forwarded to ES. In case of failure we can always re-queue the the object.
- Write a consumer to get the objects from the queue and update ES.

Apart from this you will also have to create a utility that will create an ES index from the database for first time use.

And you can also look at [Fuzzy Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) of ES that will handle typo's

Also [Completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) which also supports fuzzy search.